# Try to understand the MySQL deadlock log

Tags: mysql, deadlock

MySQL deadlock log include many information.
Recently,I look at the MySQL deadlock log,but I can't understand some section as below :

```
RECORD LOCKS space id 89 page no 3 n bits 120 index PRIMARY of table `ot`.`ta` trx id 6331 lock_mode X waiting
Record lock, heap no 50 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 9; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 4; hex 80000031; asc    1;;
 1: len 6; hex 0000000018ba; asc       ;;
 2: len 7; hex 330000019c1f2f; asc 3     /;;
 3: len 4; hex 80000004; asc     ;;
 4: len 1; hex 44; asc D;;
 5: len 4; hex 80000009; asc     ;;
 6: len 1; hex 81; asc  ;;
 7: len 6; hex 608a75900000; asc ` u   ;;
 8: len 6; hex 608a4dd616b2; asc ` M   ;;
```

I only know this transaction waiting for exclude lock on primary key ,and I don't understand what's meaning of the other information like "len" or "hex".
I can't find the reference to describe these.

Could you help to explain these or provide me some reference document?
Thanks

Comment: can you check `show full processlist` at same time.

Comment: I have never ever needed the physical record section of the deadlock report